# Mac OS X Server DNS Questions

Tags: domain-name-system, mac-osx-server

Just for a new mac server in the office, initially it was for my personal use as a web development box but now the boss wants me to set it up with all the bells and whistles it comes with.  I'm having some issues with the following... 
Lets just say my business is example.com

- I want the server's actual address to be labs.example.com and accessible to the world.  What do I need to set up at my domain registrar to let the domain know where to go, and what do I need to set up with my hosting company to make this work, and finally what do I need to set up in the server admin panel to get it to work.

It seems that DNS not working is first hurdle I need to jump but the documentation around the internet is pretty terrible.

Thank you community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want to point labs.example.com to your server, you need to add an A Record to example.com to point labs to your external IP.Ideally, your Mac server's connection to the internet will have a static IP address. If not, you want to consider getting one, especially considering most ISPs close port 80 for most dynamic IPs (see below). Then, if you have a firewall, you need to allow port 80 from the outside to go to your server. Consult your firewall's documentation for that. Finally, you need to turn on Apache on your mac server and put something worth hosting there.

In reality, your question is really quite broad so we really can't give a really great answer - do some research, and know what **specific** questions you need to ask so you can get a good answer. If you are confused about DNS, a great first step would be to consult with your registrar - if they can't help with a simple A record you need to start looking for a new DNS registrar.

Comment: They might already have a web server, so you also need one-to-one nat, if you want to host it from anther llotted IP address in your pool. This can be setup on router or by setting your ip settings to external address. Router is safer. Only open the ports you need.

Comment: Sorry for not being that clear I'll edit my question to make more sense now.